# How can I get a radio button on an form to "call up" a follow up field?

Tags: php, html, form-fields

So the form should appear thus:

Food:
O Fruits O Vegetables O I don't know.

Selecting "I don't know" should bring up a follow up question so the form now appears:

Food:
O Fruits O Vegetables * I don't know.
Well, do you like O apples and bananas or do you like O peas and carrots?

If the user selects "apples and bananas", "fruits" is then selected.  If the user selects "peas and carrots", then "vegetables" is selected.

The "likes.html" file...

```
<html>
 <body>

  <form method="post" action="food.php">
     Food<br>
   <input type="radio" name="food" value="fruits">Fruits
   <input type="radio" name="food" value="vegetables">Vegetables
   <input type="radio" name="food" value="dontknow">I don't know<br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>

 </body>

</html>
```

and the "food.php" file...

```
<html>
 <body>

  <?php

   $food = ""; $foodErr = "";

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
    if (empty($_POST["food"])) {
      $foodErr = "* food choice is required";
     }

  ?>

  <form method="post" action="<?php echo
    htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    Food <span class="error"><?php if (empty($_POST["food"])) echo    ($foodErr)        ?><br>
   <input type="radio" name="food" value="fruits" <?php if (isset($food) && $food === "fruits") echo "checked" ?>> Fruits
   <input type="radio" name="food" value="vegetables" <?php if (isset($food) &&   $food === "vegetables") echo "checked" ?>> Vegetables
   <input type="radio" name="food" value="dontknow" <?php if (isset($food) &&   $       $food === "dontknow") echo "checked" ?>> I don't know<br> 
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please, show us some code you've tried so the community can help you

Comment: Okay... and I have to say first that I appreciate all the patience and help of the far more versed.

Answer (score 1):

What you are explaining is sometimes called conditional fields in html forms. There are many ways to do this, but using CSS and the :checked pseudo class  may be the most efficient.

See https://css-tricks.com/exposing-form-fields-radio-button-css/ for a thorough explanation and example

Comment: Thanks for your response, Josh.  In my search for a solution I discovered several possible ways to go.  However, they all seemed to involved for me.  That page was one I came across and I deemed it beyond my abilities.  However, since you think it may be the most efficient means, I will revisit and try to make sense of it all.  Thank you again.

Comment: But... still at an impasse.  I can't get that to work.